# Limit mac CPU frequency without disabling Turbo Boost?

Tags: performance, cpu, kernel-extensions

Intel mobile CPUs now have a really low base frequency and a high Turbo Boost freq, e.g. i5 2.4~4.1 GHz.

Turbo at 3.8+ makes it go all the way up to 100°C. Using 'Turbo Boost Switcher' to disable TB makes the freq too low at 2.4.

Is there any way to limit CPU freq at some intermediate value like 3.2?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the intel feature it's on or off.  There is no in between setting.
Also running at above the base frequency will cause the CPU temp to creep up slowly.